# How to ensure invitation code is unique in Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I need to generate an unique user friendly code and save it into Redis either until the invited user grads it or it expires.
Since the code has  to be **user friendly** I have decided to use 6 digit number, which the frontend will divide into two groups e.g. xxx-xxx.

Now, on the backend, I have NodeJS and node_redis.
This is how I generate the random string and save it into the Redis:

```
    var invCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 100000;
    var key = "invitation-code:" + invCode;
    const TTL = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3 days

    redis.client.existsAsync(key)
        .then(res => {
            if (!res) {
                // ok, I can add the key, value pair
                return redis.client.setAsync(key, value, 'EX', TTL);
            } else {
                // I have to generate new key and check it again
                // how can I re-iterate the process???
                return null;
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            logger.info('InvitationCodeController::generate added <' + key + ', ' + value + '> pair');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            logger.error('InvitationCodeController::generate Error ' + error);
        });
```

Now, the point I cannot figure out is - in case the generated code already exists, how can I re-iterate the process, i.e. to generate another random string, format it, check in Redis and etc.
Since I have async call, I don't think any kind of loop can work for me?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize a "attempts" process like the following. 
You could also make a while loop similarly by removing the `--n` portion.

Additionally I think you should use the "NX" parameter for "SETNX" --- Set when the value does not exist. Otherwise it is possible that between the time you check redis for whether the key exists and the time you actually set it, you can overwrite some other key.  You might even rewrite it at this point so rely on SETNX throwing an error on failing to set rather than checking the value each time.

```
const process = require('process');
const redis = require("redis");
const Bluebird = require('bluebird')
Bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype)
Bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype)
const winston = require('winston');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'silly',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console({
    format: winston.format.simple()
  })]
});

const client = redis.createClient({
  host:'redis-19141.c16.us-east-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com',
  port:'19141'
});
client.auth('I6C2ISvac4suTbxSYcbsjWiz635NK8Wv');
// client.set("string key", "string val", redis.print);

var invCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 100000;
// test invCode being the same --- retry.
invCode = 111111;
var key = "invitation-code:" + invCode;
const TTL = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3 days

let value = "test";
const trySet = function(key,n){
  const used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
  logger.info(`The script uses approximately ${Math.round(used * 100) / 100} MB`);
  return client.existsAsync(key)
  .then(res => {
    logger.info("existsAsync res",res);
    if (!res) {
      logger.info("Key does not exist!");
      return client.setAsync(key, value, 'NX','EX', TTL) 
        .then(res => {
          logger.info('InvitationCodeController::generate added <' + key + ', ' + value + '> pair');
          return true;
        })
    } else {
      logger.info("Key already exists!");
      if(n > 0){
        return trySet(key,--n);
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    logger.error('InvitationCodeController::generate Error ' + error);
    return false;
  });
}

trySet(key,50).then(function(res){
  if(res){
    logger.info('trySet::success');
  }else{
    logger.info('trySet::failed');
  }
}).catch(error => {
  logger.error('trySet::error');
});
```

https://repl.it/repls/ImmediateSufficientCoin

Comment: Thanks @Cody G. - although there are some flaws in your answer, I believe I can take the essence - recursive call and `NX` option.

Answer (score 0):

Since code generation is sync process, I figure out, I can do it other way around. Here is the code:

```
    const TTL = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3 days
    var invCode = '';
    const pattern = "invitation-code:";
    var prepKey = '';

    redis.client.keysAsync(pattern + "*")
        .then(keys => {
            // these are all keys / invitation codes
            var isFound = false;
            do {
                invCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 100000;
                prepKey = pattern + invCode;
                // traverse keys to check if the invitation code matches
                keys.forEach(key => {
                    if (key === prepKey) {
                        isFound = true;
                    }
                });
            } while (isFound);
            return prepKey;
        })
        .then(key => {
            return redis.client.setAsync(key, value, 'EX', TTL);
        })
        .then(res => {
            logger.info('InvitationCodeController::generate added <' + prepKey + ', ' + value + '> pair');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            logger.error('InvitationCodeController::generate Error ' + error);
        });
```

Hope this help anyone else on the topic...